# Mac stops seeing external hard drives

Tags: usb, external-disk

My MacBook Pro (2017, 13", 2.3 GHz Intel Core i5, Mojave) suddenly stopped seeing my external hard drive.

I was working on it when the laptop lost power. The battery is dead and the power cable disconnected momentarily as I moved the computer.) I rebooted, and everything seemed okay. I started working on the files from the external drive, editing one, then rearranging some, when suddenly I got a pop up saying "disk wasn't ejected properly," and it vanished.

I tried to remount it but no luck. I confirmed that the disk is in fact okay because I could work on it on another MacBook Pro running Mojave. And yet I can't get my Mac to even see it. I restarted several times, changed the USB port, nothing. I normally use it through a Thunderbolt port on one of those adapters that connect to the two Thunderbolt ports; another hub plus an external monitor are also routed through there. I also tried it through USB2 through both the adapter and a powered hub. The light on the drive comes up but doesn't blink as it normally does when working.

It's not showing in Terminal, either. I now tried other external drives, and none will show. They get power, but the computer doesn't see them at all (no external drives show up in Terminal under `diskutil list`).

My MacBook Pro is running super low on memory, both system and working. At the time I was working on heavy Photoshop files, and I think the MacBook Pro just choked. After I closed all programs, restarted, and connected the drive directly to the MacBook Pro, it mounted. The problem hasn't gone away entirely as I can't mount other drives (USB 2 connection via adapter or hub). But at least I can see them now in Terminal or Disc Utility even if they won't mount. Does it seem right that the issue was with memory?

What happened? How can I fix it? Help!

(system_profiler SPUSBDataType output in the images. Lots of stuff connected and functioning, no drive.)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it: the issue must have been overloaded memory.

I've done some massive purging getting some free space, and then the MacBook Pro started seeing the external drives, even if I still couldn't mount them (they showed up in disc utility and in terminal).

After more cleaning I was able to mount the drive. Now, after even more cleaning and then updating to Monterey, everything works again.

Comment: Yikes. That's an indirect workaround for a yet-to-be-root-caused issue. I hope you have a good data backup system in place and are always working under the assumption that your data may disappear at any moment!

Comment: It was on a laptop I was about to ditch, so I'm now a bit less worried. Just migrated to Mac Studio.